# Java which is the correct way of initializing and parsing value for optimisation

Tags: java

Something has been bothering me lately.
I would like to learn the proper way of parsing a value for optimization purpose.

I'm curious to find which method is safer and faster?

Example:

```
msres.setSomething(api.performReturnUID(parameter1,parameter2,parameter3));
```

or

```
int temp_storage = api.performReturnUID(parameter1,parameter2,parameter3)
msres.setSomething(temp_storage);
```

Should I just execute the custom function upon set or initialize first then parse?.

Comment: There is no performance difference whatsoever.  It doesn't matter even a little bit.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, so basically both method is the same ? then i feel okay already. I'm just curious with the time taken to process it.

Comment: Any difference in a benchmark like this is going to be random noise.  Use the one you feel is easier to read and maintain long term.

Comment: @GabeSechan, got it gabe. really thanks for your time to clarify it. I was just shock looking there's difference in time taken .

Comment: @FreedomPride be very careful about generating benchmarks like this and making assumptions on it.  Its really easy to get the code wrong, and its really easy to be screwed up by random luck-  with differences this small things like scheduling of processes by the OS or a page fault in memory of the JVM can make a visible difference.

Comment: @GabeSechan, got it gabe . I think i better remove the timetaken or other users might be confuse over it.

Comment: More important than performance issues is readability and debugability. The general rule of thumb is to do one thing per line, primarily so you can more easily debug your code when the need arises. (And the need will always arise.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speed has nothing to do with this. They're equivalent and if `temp_storage` isn't used for anything else, may even generate the same bytecode.

Comment: For example, for asynchronous call for multiple users. If I use the temp_storage method, will it affect users due to race conditions in a split second?

Comment: Probably not. As I said, they may even generate the same bytecode. This question is not very good, as it concentrates mainly on a style issue. The only reason you'd choose one over the other is whether you want to use a temporary variable. Maybe you want to give it a descriptive name, maybe you don't want to nest calls like that. This is a style issue, not a functionality issue.

Comment: @FreedomPride No chance at all.  That's a stack variable, it isn't even visible to other threads.  The only way there could be a problem would be if there's a problem in both code snippets (a problem in one of those two functions).